# Which biome has the most plants on it?

Tags: starbound

I'm trying to gather plant fibers to make a bunch of bandages. However I can't seem to find  a biome with big plants on it. Which biome has the most plants on it for farming plant fibers?

Comment: Grasslands I'd imagine.  Forests might be a good bet too.  Or, if you aren't terribly picky, just head underground and cut down a bunch of roots! They're great for plant fiber.

Comment: I've had luck in forest biomes. They have small plants on the surface you can destroy with a single weapon swing that yield 1-2 plant fibers. Haven't verified but I believe they re-spawn as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The jungle biome has the most surface plants in it, which can be easily broken by a weapon to yield plant fibers. My preferred way to gather fibers is to just run along the surface of a jungle planet swinging a fast weapon.

The other best place to get plant fibers is to find a forest planet with a toxic biome. The trees in toxic biomes are tall flowers which, when cut down, drop plant fibers instead of wood.